# Building a kegerator from a wine fridge

Tags: kegerator

I am thinking of making a kegerator for 3 gallon pin lock corny kegs. Is there any issue with using a wine fridge to do this? I thought the size was right, as it can tuck away on my countertop and it has no freezer or shelves to get in the way. Has anyone done this before or has instructions on how to do this? How big of a fridge do I need for a 3 gallon keg and a 24 oz or 2.5 pound CO2 plus all the other equipment?

Comment: Fridge example: http://www.amazon.com/HOMEIMAGE-Bottle-Thermo-Electric-Cooler/dp/B007ZS4SF8/ref=cm_cd_al_qh_dp_i

Comment: The one you linked only goes down to 52 degF, not cold enough for a keg fridge.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem, and I can't see it being any different or more difficult than using a standard refrigerator. All you need to worry about is the coolant lines, which you'd have to worry about with a regular fridge anyway. I can't imagine wine fridges are any more complicated.

One thing to consider is temp. My wine fridge only goes down to 50F, so make sure whatever you get can go low enough (sometimes you might want to cold crash a keg to 30F).

I do not have the measurements offhand, and wine fridges don't usually sell by the ft³. This may be some guesswork/taking a small keg (or tape measure, or cardboard traces of your tank/kegs) to the store and trying some out. 1.5L bottles are 13.5", so that'd be a pretty standard depth, I would imagine.

The nice thing would be that there is no compressor hump, so for the most part, you are dealing with nice, cubic dimensions. However, they will vary wildly in the amount of space they allow between shelves and between the bottles on the shelves themselves.